# Client Object Model SystemUpdate

Tags: development, client-object-model, event-receivers

I need to have the `SystemUpdate` functionality from the Client Object Model.  Is there any way I can do it since the `ListItem.SystemUpdate()` does not exist?

Another solution would be to disable the EventReceiver on the list, but I don't know how to do that either.

Thanks

Comment: The SPListItem.SystemUpdate method is in the Microsoft.SharePoint namespace and in the Core Class library - not sure what you mean by "ListItem.SystemUpdate() does not exist." Could you please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: He's talking about [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem_members.aspx)

Comment: aah.. misread it..

Comment: It is available now with the latest version of the csom release, refer this below link.
[http://moresharepoints.blogspot.in/2016/09/listitemsystemupdate-is-available-with.html](http://moresharepoints.blogspot.in/2016/09/listitemsystemupdate-is-available-with.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Client Object Model have the limitations with regards to the way a List Item Update works. More specifically there is no  `SystemUpdate()` type functionality available in Client Object Model, like in the 'full' SharePoint Object Model.

If you really want to develop his functionality, then write your own custom web service that updates the document metadata using SystemUpdate so a new version isn't created and deploy it to your SharePoint Server.

Comment: Once again the ClientObjectModel has failed me :(.  Thanks for the answer.  But is there a way to Deactivate the Event Receiver then?

Comment: do you just want to disable the EventReceiver on the list using Client object model?

Comment: Yes, but I have to do it throught the Client OM